# Idiomatic C++ module use

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am thinking about using modules in my new project so I have looked at https://github.com/infiniflow/infinity/tree/main as it was recommended to me as a modern project that uses modules.

I was surprised that they pretty much just use modules as header files as I thought the whole point of modules was to get rid of them and just have a single implementation file.

Is this project using modules in a weird way or is this what modules are supposed to be?

Comment: "As header files" = splitting interface and implementation? I believe you still need to do this, otherwise you'll rebuild everything that uses the module when its implementation changes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I meant that the interface and implementation is still split into two different files. Perhaps I just misunderstood what modules are supposed to be.

Comment: I too was disappointed when I learned that it's still necessary. Modules are just supposed to improve build times due to being pre-parsed, and they don't expose the other modules they depend on if you don't specifically opt into that.

Comment: Modules are **not** header files.  They are not a single implementation file (although I suppose they could be, but then you wouldn't need to use modules because they wouldn't provide any utility value).  Modules are... *modular*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*I too was disappointed when I learned that it's still necessary.*" Define "necessary".

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean usually. You can choose to not do that, but then your incremental build times will be bad, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What do you mean by "incremental build"? If you're talking about being able to modify the internal code within a module without that forcing a recompile of all of the code including the module, yes, module units are still files and the build system still runs off of the file modification date. However, widespread use of modules makes even this recompilation way less painful because you don't have to recompile everything included by those files which include that module.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the way you would probably organize a project that you were writing from scratch with modules. However, from the history of that project, it was "refactored" into using modules, so presumably the intent was to be minimally disruptive. So header files became individual module files to ease user transitioning into the system.

One trap that this project fell into was its use of many very simple module names. Module names are global; they don't have any namespacing support. And you cannot include two projects that create modules that are named the same. Even if the name is only used internally.

So you would never be able to use this project with some other project that uses the module name `function`, even if neither of them exports that module name. Most of the modules this project uses should have been module *partitions*, not actual modules (or, failing that, at least use some kind of `project_prefix.name` for the name of these internal sub-modules) . Partition names within a module cannot conflict with partition names from some other module (this is why partitions exist).

So no, this project does not exhibit good practices.

> the whole point of modules was to get rid of them and just have a single implementation file

If you're talking about the conceptual distinction between headers and source files (interface vs. implementation), no, even the earliest version of the current module proposal had a distinction here.

Virtually every C++ build system rebuilds files based on file modification timestamps. If you modify a file, then the build system assumes everything dependent on that file is going to have to be modified. So if you modify a file that defines a module being imported by something else, that something else needs to get recompiled. Even if the modification you made isn't one that changed the module in a way that matters.

While a module-based build system might *in theory* attempt to avoid this, in practice it's extremely difficult to implement. What would have to happen is that the module gets rebuilt and compared with the previous compiled version of that module. If they didn't change, then there's no need to cascade that module rebuild into the included modules. It's easier to just let the file modification date handle things.

So if you want to limit the recompilation cascade resulting from modifying the implementation of a module, those files need to be separate from the interface units of a module.